# Should I use multiple images in react native app?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native. Can anyone explain to me how react native resizes images? Will an image lose quality if I resize it with width & height props? 
Should I have many images for large, medium and small screen?

For example, if I have an image with dimensions 150x150, will it lose quality on large or small screen if I render it like that:

```
<Image source={require('path_to_150x150_image')} style={{width: 50, height: 50}}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quality shouldn't be lost when resizing, but as with image resize if you scale up a low-res image it will look bad on a high-res screen. The easy thing to do would be to start with a large image and scale down if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am also fetching same issue with one of my application. Finally i have developed Native module with my react code. You will find step by step detail [here](https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-resize-image).